# collatz algorithm that returns first integer when at least input (n) in length

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

Here are my instructions:

Consider the following process: Start with some positive integer. If the number is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1. If it is even, divide it by 2. For every number that has ever been tried, repeating this process eventually leads to the number 1. For example, starting with 6 we get the sequence 6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1. That is a sequence of length 9.

Write a function collatz that takes a parameter n and returns the first integer for which the generated sequence is at least n in length.

This is my current code:

```
def collatz( n ):

    seq = []
    seq.append( n )

    while n > 1:

        if n % 2 != 0:

            n = int( n * 3 ) + 1
            seq.append( n )

        else:

            n = int( n / 2 )
            seq.append( n )

    if len( seq ) < seq[ 0 ]:
        return len( seq )

    else: 

        return seq[ 1 ]
```

My current code works for an input of 10 which outputs 7 correctly, as well as an input of 6 which outputs 3 correctly, but for an input of 3 it outputs 10 when it should output 3.

I am incredibly confused by this question and cannot wrap my head around what it's even asking. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your task description: `Write a function collatz that takes a parameter n and returns the first integer for which the generated sequence is at least n in length.` But you are doing something else, you are starting from the length `n` for some reason and hope it fits. who said it should be the candidate? The "good" test cases are pure luck.

Comment: @amit The task makes no sense to me though, given what should result from each input. I have no idea how an inout of 10 results in 7 since there is no 7 integer in the sequence..

Comment: @beginner_coder because the length of the series started at `10` is `7`.

Comment: Let me define the problem formally: `collatz(n) = x such that len(seq(x)) >= n and for all y < x, len(seq(y)) < n`

Comment: @amit Your definition is very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what the question is asking you to do is this:

Write a function collatz that takes a number n and returns the smallest integer whose generated sequence is longer than n.

Some example outputs:

```
>>>colatz(1)
1
>>>colatz(2)
2
>>>colatz(3)
3
>>>colatz(4)
3
>>>colatz(9)
6
```

The function you have right now seems to be generating the sequence for a given number correctly. After that though, I don't think what you are returning makes any progress towards answering the question.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like I understand this better now!!

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers :)

Answer (score 2):

"Write a function collatz that takes a parameter n and returns the first integer for which the generated sequence is at least n in length"

So you would be writing a function to find a collatz sequence that is at least of length n **and** return the interger it starts with. Not a collatz sequence that starts with n.